# How can i remove empty bars from dc.js row chart, whenever the dimension is null or empty, there appears an empty bar on row chart

Tags: javascript, dc.js

How can i remove empty bars from dc.js row chart, whenever the dimension is null or empty, there appears an empty bar on row chart.

[image: Empty Bar in row chart]

Comment: What do you mean by "the dimension is null or empty"? Could you post some code and sample data? (A fiddle would be even better.) I'm guessing the key function evaluates to blank/undefined/null for some values. You could remove them with a fake group, but I think it indicates data that needs to be cleaned better.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use fake group

```
const remove_empty_bins = (source_group) => {
    return {
        all: () => {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                // here your condition
                return d.key !== null && d.key !== '' && d.value !== 0; // etc. 
            });
        }
    };
}

let myFilteredGroup = remove_empty_bins(myGroup);
```