# How to remove empty bars from facet_grid in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap, facet-grid

In order to arrange the bars on each grid level, using drlib package.
However, it seems to work for facet_wrap but not grid as there are empty bars found.

Is there a way to get rid of empty bars ?
Similar questions (Not R):
[How can i remove empty bars from dc.js row chart, whenever the dimension is null or empty, there appears an empty bar on row chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587863/how-can-i-remove-empty-bars-from-dc-js-row-chart-whenever-the-dimension-is-null)

[Remove empty bars from grouped barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316555/remove-empty-bars-from-grouped-barplot)

```
library(tidyverse)

library(drlib)
viz <- data.frame(type = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",4)),
                  project = c("ABC","BCD","CDE","EFG","FGI","GIK","IKL","KLM","LMO"),
                  complexity = c(.8,.95,.6,.8,.9,.3,.7,.2,.6),
                  impact = c(1,.8,.7,.8,.9,.4,.8,.6,.5),
                  relevance = c(.8,.5,.7,.9,.1,.8,.7,.7,.8),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

viz_lng <- viz %>% 
    gather(-c(1,2), key = category, value = importance)%>% 
    arrange(desc(importance))

ggplot(viz_lng[which(viz_lng$importance>0),], 
       aes(x = reorder_within(project, importance, category, ), 
           y= importance, group = project, fill = project)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    scale_x_reordered() +
    facet_grid(vars(category), vars(type), scales="free_x")  +
    guides(fill=FALSE) + theme_bw() +
    theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 14),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 14))
```

Expected result would be to have arranged bars however without no empty bars see in each grid level.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use the `drlib` package? Unfortunately `drlib` is not available for my version of `r`. Could you provide pictures of what you did and the desired result?

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

drlib is r package downloadable r package using devtools (https://github.com/dgrtwo/drlib). It is build for customizing the facets. reprex code will reproduce the same plot I had. Basically, if facet_grid is replaces by facet_wrap, code seesm to work but not customized.